# Select unique record from 2 table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 table :

_ Table user: ID ( primary key) , Name, phonenumber.

_ Table class : ID (primary key), Subject (primary key).

I want to select ID, Name, Phonenumber from table user which have record ID in table class without duplicate ID.For example:

```
 ID    Name    PhoneNumber
 1      a       012312
 2      b       345678  
 3      c       232321

ID  Subject
2    abc
3    def
2    def
3    abc
```

The result will be

```
ID    Name   PhoneNumber
2      b        345678
3      c        232321
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Aren't `ID`s 2 and 3 duplicates?

Comment: in the table 2 I have 2 record as primary key. It can have duplicate ID

Comment: then what does *without duplicate ID* means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id,name,phonenumber
FROM
    user
    JOIN class on user.id = class.ID
```

or

```
SELECT
    id,name,phonenumber
FROM
    user
WHERE
    id IN (SELECT id FROM class)
```

or

```
SELECT
    id,name,phonenumber
FROM
    user
WHERE
    EXISTS (select 1 from class where user.id = class.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?

```
select ID, Name, PhoneNumber
from Table1
where exists (select 1 from Table2 where Table2.ID = Table1.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct ID, Name, PhoneNumber FROM User, Class WHERE User.ID = Class.ID
```